# Twitter Bootstrap Navbar Dropdown Styling

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am in the process of styling the top navbar but can not see how to remove the top caret on the dropdown panel (please see image below). Please let me know if you can help. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Post your code please :)

Comment: @Alesanco hello, it is just the generic css at this point with a few color changes

Comment: @Arkady, please post the html from your developer's console so we can identify where that up caret is coming from.  Bootstrap does preprocessing so that caret might not be in the CSS/html source anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove it by overriding the Bootstrap CSS like this..

```
/* remove the triangle */
.navbar .nav>li>.dropdown-menu:before,.navbar .nav>li>.dropdown-menu:after {
  content: none;
}
```

Working example: http://bootply.com/66576